# Is there a way to search music in a 2005 BMW 320D Touring

Tags: audio, 320d

Is there a way to search music in the BMW 320D Touring menu?

I also can't scroll through the music list in a cd/dvd. Only lets me scroll through the songs already on screen.

How can i scroll through the entire playlist?

Comment: What year is your car?

Answer (score 4):

There is no search feature on the  2005 BMW 320D Touring OEM stereo.

As well, when selecting a playlist you cannot browse individual songs as you can if you select songs and browse through them.